# Android OBD response conversion to decimal

Tags: android, hex, obd-ii

In my app i send four basic commands to OBD ports and get back hex data...
I don't know why if i send the command:

ME: 010c

Car: 10c410c0000

Why the message don't start with 4?
And get only 410c and the data that the obd receive from car?

I use this method for manage hex response and convert it to human readable data, and RawData is a String that take the message and clear all space, like this
41 0c 00 00 = 410c0000

```
   public String getCalculatedResult() {

        //TODO devo convertire i dati da esadecimale a decimale ed effettuare i calcoli
        int calculatedData = 0;
        String dataToShow = null;

        //Log.d("ObdCommand", "rawData: " + rawData.substring(3));
        calculatedData = Integer.parseInt(rawData.substring(7), 16);


        if (Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(rawData.substring(3,4)),
                    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher("410D").find()){

            Log.d("ObdCommand", "dentro 410D: ");
            //Velocità veicolo km/h

            dataToShow = String.valueOf(calculatedData) + " Km/h";
            Log.d("ObdCommand", "rawData: " + dataToShow);

        }else if (Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(rawData.substring(3,4)),
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher("410C").find()){

            Log.d("ObdCommand", "dentro 410C: ");

            //Giri minuto veicolo rpm
            calculatedData = calculatedData/4;

            dataToShow = String.valueOf(calculatedData) + " rpm";

        }else if (rawData.substring(3).startsWith("4105")){

            //Temperatura refrigetante C°
            calculatedData = calculatedData - 40;

            dataToShow = String.valueOf(calculatedData) + " C°";


        }else if (rawData.substring(3).startsWith("4151")){
            //Tipo di carburante
            if (rawData.substring(7).startsWith("09")){

                //Benzina
                dataToShow = "Benzina";

            }else if (rawData.substring(7).startsWith("0d")){

                //Metano
                dataToShow = "Metano";
            }
        }


        return dataToShow;
    }
```

I use the rawData.substring(7) because 3 is the characters that i tell at the start of post

10c

And the other 4 are

410c

So i get only the value that i need to decimal... but sometimes i get outof bound....

Someone have some idea to get this with no problems?

Thanks